# using non-capturing lambda as function pointer argument to a variadic template function gives "no matching function call"

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, function-pointers, variadic-templates

I am currently experimenting with writing a "foreach with" for an ecs.

```
template <typename... T>
void foreach (void (*func)(Entity e, T... args)){
  std::vector<Entity> intersection;
  // ... Find all entities with all the types
  for (size_t i = 0; i < intersection.size(); i++)
    func(intersection[i], *getComp<T>(intersection[i])...);
}
```

It's working perfectly with a function argument

```
void foo(Entity e, int i)
{
  setComp<int>(e, (int) e);
}

foreach(foo); // Works as expected
```

But not with the same function copy and pasted as lambda

```
foreach( // even if foreach<int>
    [](Entity e, int i) {
        setComp<int>(e, (int) e);
    }); // error "no matching function call" "no instance of template matches"
```

Changing foreach to accept lambdas

```
template <typename... T, typename F>
void foreach (F func){
  std::vector<Entity> intersection;
  // ... Find all entities with all the types
  for (size_t i = 0; i < intersection.size(); i++)
    func(intersection[i], *getComp<T>(intersection[i])...);
}
```

now produces an error "no match for call to" with lambda and "too few arguments to function" with foo, both at func(...);.

I'm probably overseeing something, but even after scouring google and SO I just can't find what.

I'll probably just gonna use the function pointer variant and give up on passing lambdas as that works at least, but would be very gratefull if somebody could point out what dumb me has overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that with

```
template <typename... T>
void foreach (void (*func)(Entity e, T... args))
```

the variadic list of types `T...` is deduced from `func` arguments.

With

```
template <typename... T, typename F>
void foreach (F func)
```

the `T...` list can't be deduced anymore from `func`.

So you can't call

```
foreach( // even if foreach<int>
    [](Entity e, int i) {
        setComp<int>(e, (int) e);
    });
```

You have to explicit `T...`

```
// ....VVVVV
foreach<int>(
    [](Entity e, int i) {
        setComp<int>(e, (int) e);
    });
```

Comment: u.u Jep, dumb me. I even tried <int,void(*)(Entity,int)> but not simply <int>. Works now though. Huge thanks. :D